# How to know if you have memory size problems or if that's just the JVM growing empty?

Tags: java, memory

The question is the following :

I noticed on my server that the memory is 100% full.

Now does that mean that :

- my tomcat needs to much memory, and that I should either optimize my code or add some memory to my server
- the JVM has grown in anticipation of its content growth

The basic question is : should I be worried ?

Comment: 100% full heap or 100% full physical memory?

Comment: When your memory is 100% full, you will get an OutOfMemoryError. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: 100% full physical memory. Is there a way to see the memory usage inside the JVM (see the free space vs occupied space) ?

Comment: Your memory should never be 100% physically full. The OS will always ensure a small point is free.  The OS will also tend to cache disk as much as possible so you can have a system with appears to be almost 100% full when very little is used by applications. (Mostly used by cached files)  Which OS do you have?  If you are using linux can you do `head /proc/meminfo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `jvisualvm`, connect it to your application VM, perform a manual GC and see if there is any memory left?

Answer (score 0):

> ..should I be worried ?

Start worrying when the app. gets `OutOfMemoryErrors`.